# How old is Mai in Next Gen?

Tags: next-gen

How old is Mai in Next Gen? Common Sense Media claims she is twelve years old, but I can't find that officially confirmed (and plus, the movie implies she's older.)

Is there an official source to Mai's age?

Comment: *"We came up with the story of Mai Su — a teenager with memories she’d rather forget"* - So she's at least thirteen.

Comment: I've twitted at the directors. Hopefully they'll respond with an answer

Comment: @Valorum - You could try [Wang Nima](), the author of the original Chinese online rage comic *7723* which *Next Gen* was adapted from. Nima is the founder and editor of China’s leading ‘rage comics’ website Baozou Manhua.

Comment: @Jeeped - Was Mai even in the original comics? https://www.syfy.com/syfywire/next-gen-story-behind-netflixs-biggest-animated-film

Comment: @Valorum - My bad. I thought I saw Mai in the original comic but it turned out to be concept art for the subsequent animated film. **Joe Ksander** would be the better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directors indicated (in [an interview](https://www.animationmagazine.net/streaming/building-a-girl-and-robot-dream-team-for-next-gen-on-netflix/)) that she's a "*teenager*", so as a minimum we know that she's something between thirteen and nineteen, and presumably on the lower side of that range given how she's portrayed.

> **Kevin Adams and Joe Ksander:** *The movie was based on a short online comic from the Chinese multimedia company Baozou. It contained the core of the idea — what if every night, a robot had to choose which memories to keep and which to delete? That’s a cool, compelling high-concept hook. It was our job to make a world and a story that best took advantage of that hook. We asked ourselves, what is the perfect foil for a robot who doesn’t want to lose his memories? **We came up with the story of Mai Su — a teenager with memories she’d rather forget.** All of us are a little broken, in some ways. In the case of 7723 (also known as “Project 77” — our robot hero) we made him literally broken. So, we have two broken characters who need each other to survive. And then we added exploding robots.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Building a Girl-and-Robot Dream Team for Netflix’s ‘Next Gen’](https://www.animationmagazine.net/streaming/building-a-girl-and-robot-dream-team-for-next-gen-on-netflix/)</sup></sub>

This ties in with the line from the film where her mother accuses her of moodiness.

> "Are you going to at least look at me **while you're being all teenagery**"

And 77's estimation that she's a "juvenile", suggesting under 17.

[image]